# dropdown getting background from parent div css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

the problem i facing is that the dropdown list is inheriting the background from parent div.

[image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTSNF.jpg)

all i want is that the dropdown only have background for ul element not the whole parent div.

```css
div.main-category {
  background: #9f76da;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav> li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 32.5%;
}
.nav>li>ul.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #9f76da !important;
  border-radius: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-category">
  <ul class="nav nav-bar">

    <li class="dropdown ">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Men <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown ">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Women <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </li>
    <li class="dropdown ">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop1" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Kids <span class="caret"></span> </a> 
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
        </li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Backgrounds are **transparent** unless defined otherwise. Just define a different color for the backround of the `ul`.

Comment: Post the full code of css related to that dropdown. So that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You use nav > li twice as well as the nav > li > ul.
With this you give everything the same color.

Remove the color from the div and put the purple color on the a of the main items

```
.nav li.dropdown > a {   
  background: #9f76da;    
  display:block; 
  width:100%;  
}
```

give the dropdown items the color you want and use display: block

https://jsfiddle.net/bond708/v1ecmsfo/